# Generic collection of generic items in a class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-2.0

I'm trying to create a class that accepts two generic types (IQueue, IItem) for example:

```
public class Coordinator<T,K>
    where T : IQueue<K>
    where K : IItem
{
    private T<K> collection = new T<K>();
}
```

Where:

```
public interface IQueue<T> where T : IItem
{
}

public class MyQueue<T> : IQueue<T>
    where T : IItem
{
}
```

But the compiler does not like:

```
private T<K> collection = new T<K>();
```

Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Activator is still probably a good partial answer, but it doesn't work out just yet. =) Too bad for the deleted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do the following:

```
public interface IQueue<T> where T : IItem
{
}

public class MyQueue<T> : IQueue<T>
    where T : IItem
{
}
```

Because you are saying: The coordinator gets an IQueue, but you are trying to construct a MyQueue with more specific information.

Using the already discussed `Activator`, you can do this without compiler errors:

```
class Coordinator <T,K>
    where T : IQueue<K>
    where K : IItem
{
    private T collection = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: I had : 

        private T collection = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

But they both work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have expected that in "where T : IQueue where K : IItem" there was a sequence, however it actually needs to be explicity defined *now*.  It would be a nice feature if this did work in the future though.  Intuitively what you ask makes sense to me.

here's a suggested way to approach it.

```
public class Coordinator<T> where T : IQueue<T>, new()
{
    private T collection = new T();  
}
public interface IQueue<T>{}
public interface IItem{}
```

Comment: It would be far more readable if you could 'sequence' them up like I tried, but I guess what you say makes sense with what we have.

Comment: typed this in, and went away to find the same answer above.  btw: "(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));" is a nice touch.

Comment: [edit]: see the new() above in where clause.  This allows you to avoid Activator.

Comment: Only if you have a parameterless constructor though I assume?

Comment: yep, that's right. It's a limitation of new(). new() must have paramaterless constructor, otherwise compiler will complain.